# New user held with searching array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to search an array and if the two Strings are matched then it will return true otherwise false, firstly i want to search to see if the account is already there if so then search Code if the two exsis then return true

```
public boolean searchArray(String account, String code) {    
    for (Accounts a : bAccounts) {
        if (a.getAccount().equals(account)) {
            for (Accounts c : bAccounts) {
                if (c.getCode().equals(Code))
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

    return false;
}
```

Think I've got a little lost within this search method, can anyone please help me on this, thanks. This all compiles fine but doesn't seem to return anything. I have get methods in my Accounts class which has get and set methods for Account and Sort.

Comment: Very confusing names. Variable names should not be capitalized and type names are singular, not plural. Also, are the two strings supposed to match for a single object, or for any pair of objects?

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean searchArray(String account, String code) {    
    for (Accounts a : bAccounts) {
        if (a.getAccount().equals(account)
                  && a.getCode().equals(code)) {                
            return true;                    
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Inner for should be removed.

Comment: This is always returning false

Comment: Then it is not a problem of searching but your data.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you'll accept nulls for account and code parameters.

If null values are possible/desirable to compare, this is what I suggest:

```
public boolean searchArray(String account, String code) {

    for (Account a : accounts) {
        if (account == null) {
            if (code == null) {
                if ((a.getAccount() == null) && (a.getCode() == null)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                if ((a.getAccount() == null) && code.equals(a.getCode())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (code == null) {
                if (account.equals(a.getAccount()) && (a.getCode() == null)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                if (account.equals(a.getAccount()) && code.equals(a.getCode())) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you won't consider nulls for account and code parameters, I suggest this:

```
public boolean searchArray(String account, String code) {
    // if you won't consider nulls then there's no need to search
    // when at least one of them is null
    if ((account == null) || (code == null)) {
        return false;
    }

    for (Account a : accounts) {
        if (account.equals(a.getAccount()) && code.equals(a.getCode())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I am using this to compare to see if an object exsists with thoose same details when a new Account is addedd to accounts, it will never be passed null values as I have handlers that deal with null field at the point of entry, but even this is returning null in every instance. I have printed out what is being passed and it is printing out valid account and code but it just continuiosly returns false.